# SQL Server TOP constraint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was wondering if there was a constraint or way to limit the total number of rows a table returns if there is no top clause in the query executed. We can't easily modify the SQL being executed so the solution needs to be on the db level.

We have a lot of queries our system blindly builds that are like

```
select * from table where email = 'john'
```

and when we had small tables this worked fine but now our tables have +10000 rows and this is becoming inefficient.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: First of all: a `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is pointless - you want to top 5 rows - but ordered by ***what?!?!*** You need to always define an `ORDER BY`. Once you do - you can use an index to speed up this `ORDER BY` clause (but not if you use `SELECT *` .... stop doing that - select exactly those columns that you really need)

Comment: If code broken is, code fix you should. In other words, no amount of server tinkering can fix bad code.

Comment: Hmm, a server setting that means a `SELECT` without a `WHERE` clause *doesn't* return all rows? I can't ever see that causing problems :)

Answer (score 4):

The answer is "yes".  One way is using "set rowcount".  Another way is to use any facility built into your query connection for this purpose.

For instance:

```
SET ROWCOUNT 10
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

This sets the maximum rows returned to 10 for any subsequent queries.  However, to fit this into your application, we need more information, such as how that application is accessing the database.

Answer (score 1):

it's a bit convoluted:

```
CREATE TABLE temp
(
y  char(9) PRIMARY KEY,
x  char(9)
);

insert into temp (x, y) values ('j', 'hello');
insert into temp (x, y) values ('j', 'world');
insert into temp (x, y) values ('q', 'foo');
insert into temp (x, y) values ('q', 'bar');


with myCTE(x,y,r) as
(
select 
  x
  ,y
  , r = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
from temp
)
select * from myCTE where r <= 3;
```